# Maximum item caching limit of any list in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-lazyloading

What will happen if we keep on loading thousands of items in any type list in Android? Will Android be able to recycle it correctly?

Comment: Combination of answers given by "Glen Pierce" and "Smartiz" clears the doubt that I have. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Short Answer

In your case, there Would not be any problem in recycling of list view or recycler view.

> Long Answer

The list view or recycler view would just load and show the amount of data which are visible on the UI. So the size of the items in it is not any problem.

BUT

there are some cases which would make problem.
for example if you put a recycler view inside a Scroll view!
In such cases all of the items are loaded and there is no GC. That's where you would have big problems with lots of data.

Answer (score 0):

List is an Interface, not a class, so there are ArrayLists and LinkedLists and several other types, but ArrayLists for example can handle up to Integer.MAX_VALUE elements. I've never had a problem with an ArrayList and garbage collection at least and thousands of items is far below the limits of that class.

Comment: I come up with this question because, the data that I am loading in each recyclerview's item is also big. So I thought what if I keep on lazy loading such a huge data in Android then there may be possibility of data loss due to caching memory finished or low ram. But according to you it will not happen, right?

Comment: I wouldn't generally worry too much about this. However, if you're approaching the memory limits of an Android application (which you can find with getMemoryClass() in ActivityManager - it varies by device and OS), you might need to move the data into persistent storage (the device's hard drive). How much memory are you thinking your app might eat up?

Comment: No I am not sure about it. Each item in RV has at least 10 strings. And I am not sure how much memory I need to cache say atleast 1000x10 strings which will be loaded only once throughout the app in view pager. One thing that I want to mention, I am not loading this this again and again, user can switch different pages in app and the loaded list will be there already loaded.